# 1 bit adder-subtractor circuit truth table

Tags: digital-logic

today in class my teacher mentioned the truth table for an adder-subtractor circuit was the same as that of a full adder... I have been trying to understand and wrap my head around this fact but I simply can't. Would someone please explain it to me ??

Comment: So, a full adder has three inputs and two outputs.  Which means it's really easy to cook up.  Why don't you make up the two truth tables, and compare them?

Comment: I know how to make a full adder. The problem is im unsure how the adder-subtractor would look

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder%E2%80%93subtractor

Comment: How do adders handle the CARRY? How must a subtractor handle the BORROW/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. but im pretty sure thats probably the answer to all my questions